# Map ip+port to internal website name

Tags: internal-dns

I have a LAN web application running in our organization on a Ubuntu 20.04 at this address:
http://192.168.0.104:8084/

Rest of devices are Windows and our servers are Windows Server too. So our clients are accessing the application typing the whole route http://192.168.0.104:8084/ on web browser.

I would like clients can access the web application by using an internal domain name i.e. http://web.organization.com/ and it resolves internally to http://192.168.0.104:8084/. But I do not know if it is even possible to configure something like this in our Windows DNS server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To little rep for a simple comment:

DNS can only point the more easily remembered host/domain name such as web.example.com to an IP-address. (And that should be possible with your Windows DNS server.)

When you don't run a web service on the default port, DNS won't allow you (yet) to instruct a we browser: *"when connecting to `http://web.eaxmple.com` ; do not connect to the default port for the HTTP protocol, port 80, but instead connect to custom port 8084."*

You solve that by: either run your web application on port 80, or you configure a reverse proxy on port 80, that will forward HTTP requests (for the specific `web.example.com` host) from port 80 to custom port 8084. When you already run another website on port 80, many web servers come with reverse proxy functionality and can be configured with virtual hosts so that only requests for `web.example.com` will be proxied to port 8084.

Comment: Thank you! I understand, i will change the web app to publish on por 80 instead. However, how can I configure my windows DNS server to map that 192.168.0.104:80 to web.example.com?

Comment: That depends on the Windows release, if you already have the correct roles enabled etc. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/ipam/add-a-dns-resource-record

Comment: perfect, it definetly answers my question